# delete a row from select result set

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

so this is my code , it's pretty obvious whats going on

```
$resultset = $this->m_model->getDetails();

foreach($resultset->result() as $k=>$v )
{
   if($v->condition) 
   unset($resultset->result[$k]) ;
}
```

obviously

```
   unset($resultset->result[$k]) ;
```

doesn't work ... how can i delete from my result set ?

Comment: you are getting a result object. you can also get a result array. like $resultset->result_array(); then filter for your conditions and send the modified array to the view. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$resultset = $this->m_model->getDetails();
$result=$resultset->result();
foreach( $result as $k=>$v )
{
   if($v->condition) 
   unset($result[$k]) ;
}
```

Comment: thanx , but is there any way to deleted from original result set/variable   ? i dont want to change my view at all .... if i do it like this i have to change my view to handle result set without `->result()` ... it's a tiny change but i prefer not to do it for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Playing off of FaceOfJock's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860864/1893629), try this:</strike>

```
$resultset = $this->m_model->getDetails();
$result = $resultset->result();

foreach($result as $k=>$v)
{
   if($v->condition) 
   unset($result[$k]);
}

$resultset->result() = (object) $result;
```

After looking into this more, I don't think what you are looking to do is possible. However, a better solution might be to control this from your model. You can use CI's active records like such:

```
$this->db->where('some_column !=', 'some_value');
```

Comment: After looking into more I don't think it's possible `unset`ting the way you are looking for, however I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.